# Serialize DateTime splitting date and time

Tags: console-application, asp.net-core-3.1, system.text.json

Imagine an instance of this class with the time of May 27th 2020, 2:02 PM

```
public class Example
{
 public DateTime When{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to serialize the property `When` like this

```
{
  "date": "2020-05-27",
  "time": "14:02"
}
```

How do I serialize this using class attributes ? And how do I deserialize it? Do I need to change my class to work with this json?

Comment: *How do I serialize this using class attributes ?* - you will need to create a [custom `JsonConverter<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to) for such a scenario, you can't split a single property into multiple JSON properties purely via attributes.